# Proving a function has no proper input validation

Tags: python, regex, sanitization

**The Problem:**

I have this artificial example function:

```
def test_function(target, words):
    pattern = re.compile(r"|".join(words))

    return bool(pattern.search(target))
```

which takes a list of words and dynamically constructs a regular expression pattern *without proper escaping* the words in the list.

Usage samples:

```
text = "hello world!"

print(test_function(text, ["test"]))  # prints False
print(test_function(text, ["hello"]))  # prints True
print(test_function(text, ["test", "world"]))  # prints True
```

**The Question:**

How can I test this function to *prove that there is no proper regular expression escaping or input sanitization*?

In other words, what items in a `words` list should I provide to "break" this function?

---

I've tried several "evil" regexes to simulate catastrophic backtracking and force the function to hang like `(x+x+)+y` or `(a+)+`, but the function just returns `False` *instantly* and there is no indication of a problem.

Comment: an empty string that will always return "true" *(whatever the other words)*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are plenty of ways you could do this. For example, a word that isn't a valid regex:

```
>>> test_function('a', ['*'])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 2, in test_function
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/re.py", line 190, in compile
    return _compile(pattern, flags)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/re.py", line 245, in _compile
    raise error, v # invalid expression
sre_constants.error: nothing to repeat
```

or a word that matches everything as a regex:

```
>>> test_function('a', ['.*'])
True
```

or a word that doesn't match what it should as a regex:

```
>>> test_function('$^', ['$^'])
False
```

or a word that ends in a backslash and escapes the `|`:

```
>>> test_function('a', ['\\', 'a'])
False
```

Catastrophic backtracking works too:

```
>>> test_function('a'*100, ['(a+)+b'])
# Hangs.
```

Comment: Oh yeah, the "nothing to repeat" is a good one. Thanks! Can we simulate a catastrophic backtracking and see the function behaving very slowly?

Comment: @alecxe: Yeah, that'd work too. I've added an example with catastrophic backtracking.